# Is this redundant?

Tags: sentence-structure

I checked books.google.com to see whether I can put these two sentences together, and I couldn't find any results.

> "He had to get out of the army, whom he hated too much to serve now, **and to** take his beloved ones to the other side of the border safe and sound."

Is the sentence below more correct? (It seems to have a different meaning, doesn't it?)

> He had to get out of the army, whom he hated too much to serve now, **and** take his beloved ones to the other side of the border safe and sound.

Comment: The original structure is "had to do X and to do Y"..the revised structure is "had to do X and Y". I don't think the **to** is redundant in the first sentence.

Comment: As an aside I don't think you can use whom as a pronoun for army. It's not lively enough. You want to use which.

Comment: I think it makes no difference;  the use of "to" before take is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, however the first sentence seems to say that he had to quit the army and take his beloved to the other side of the border, in no particular order - either one can happen first.

The second sentence clarifies the order of what he will do; in this case he has to quit the army first, and second, he will take his beloved to the other side of the border.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first sentence is more correct. It is not redundant and it only follows parallelism in the usage of infinitives.

Good day, sir